# Modeling $t \in [a,b] \; \Rightarrow y_{[a,b] }=1$, asking for alternatives if any

Tags: linear-programming, mathematical-modeling, integer-programming

Suppose you have a variable $t\ge 0 $, I want to model the following statement :
$$
t \in [a_i,b_i] \; \Rightarrow y_i =1
$$
I am assuming $t$ belongs to a unique interval among the ones proposed.

I am doing it as follows :
$$
\sum_i y_i = 1 \\
t \le \sum_i b_i y_i \\
t \ge \sum_i a_i y_i \\
y_i \in \{0,1\}
$$

Just wondering if there is another way to do it (there most certainly is !).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could break up your two inequalities into a bunch of "big M" type inequalities of the form$$t\le b_i + (B-b_i)(1-y_i)$$and$$t\ge a_i + (A-a_i)(1-y_i)$$where $A$ and $B$ are respectively the smallest and largest legal values of $t$. Between your formulation and this one, I don't know which would fare better in terms of solution time.

If the intervals are consecutive ($a_{i+1}=b_i$), you could try an [SOS2 formulation](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2015/10/piecewise-linear-functions-in-mip-models.html) (assuming your solver understands SOS2 constraints). Again, it's an empirical question which results in the best solver performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input. Doesn't your formulation model $y_i = 1 \Rightarrow t \in [a_i, b_i ] ?$ What forces $y_i$ to take value $1$ if $t$ is in the interval ?

Comment: I'm retaining the $\sum_i y_i = 1$ constraint. So $y_i =0\implies y_j=1$ for some $j\neq i$, which then puts $t$ in interval $j$. In other words, $y_i =0\implies t\notin [a_i, b_i]$.